# Declaration and prototype difference

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, function-prototypes

What is the difference between declaration and prototype in C? In which situations they are called declarations and in which prototypes?

Comment: there is nothing called variable prototype.

Comment: All function prototypes are also declarations. But some declarations are not prototypes. Specifically, if the function parameter list does not specify the types of the parameters (or void), then it is not a prototype.

Comment: @M.M instead of "(or void)", I think you meant to say "(or empty)". K&R 2Ed., A8.6.3 *Function Declarators* states: "In the new-style declaration, the parameter list specifies the types of the parameters. As a special case, the declarator for a new-style function with no parameters has a parameter type list consisting solely of the keyword `void`." To clarify "new-style," page 202 states: "In the new-style, the types of parameters are explicit and are part of the type of the function; such a declaration is also called a **function prototype**."

Comment: @ClintPachl I meant "or void". But maybe my sentence could be parsed in two ways. "or void" comes under things that the list must not do if it is not a prototype. To rephrase: It is not a prototype if the list neither specifies the type of the parameters, nor is `(void)`.

Comment: @M.M You were right. Saying "nor" helped me understand my misinterpretation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR;** All prototypes are declarations, but not all declarations are prototypes.

*Declaration* is the generic terminology used in the standards, *prototype* is more specific.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. [...]

and from §6.7.6,

> Each declarator declares one identifier, and asserts that when an operand of the same
>   form as the declarator appears in an expression, it designates a function or object with the
>   scope, storage duration, and type indicated by the declaration specifiers.

On the other hand, from chapter §6.2.1

> [....] *A function
>   prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.*

So, one liner, prototype is more complete form (including types of parameter) of declaration.

---

About "identifier": chapter §6.4.2.1,

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore `_`, the
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
>   one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. [...]

and in chapter §6.2.1,

> An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or
>   enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter. [....]

Answer (score 16):

A declaration introduces a name:

```
int a;    // "a" has type int
```

A function declaration (that is not also a prototype) only introduces the name of a function and its return type:

```
int f();   // a function call expression "f(x, y, ...)" has type int
```

However, such a function declaration does not specify which arguments are valid for the function call; in other words, it does not specify the function *signature*. This is done by a function prototype (which is a kind of declaration):

```
int g1(void);         // "g1" takes no arguments, "g()" has type int
int g2(float, char);  // "g2" takes two arguments
int g3(int, ...);     // "g3" takes at least one argument
```

Whether a function prototype is visible at the time of a function call has important consequences on the call arguments: If no prototype is visible, all arguments undergo default argument promotions. By contrast, if a prototype is available, function arguments are converted to the types of the corresponding formal parameters (and the program is ill-formed if the number of arguments doesn't match or if any of the conversions would be ill-formed).

To explore this further, observe that there are certain "impossible" combinations: If we had a declaration `int g2();` and a definition `int g2(float, char) { return 0; }`, it would never be possible to call `g2` just with the declaration, because the formal parameter types cannot result from default argument promotions. It is generally advisable to always use prototype declarations and never use non-prototype declarations.

Finally, it is possible to call a prototyped function with more arguments than it has parameters, if the prototype ends in the ellipsis (`...`). The use of `<stdarg.h>` to get at those arguments requires that a function prototype is visible at the time of call for such a variable-argument function.

Comment: A prototype is also a declaration.

Comment: `void h() {}` is not a prototype, e.g. `int main() { if ( 0 ) main(5); }` is a legal program

Comment: @M.M: Are you sure? Reference?

Comment: C11 6.9.7/1 "If the declarator includes a parameter type list, [...] such a declarator also serves as a function prototype". There's no extra case for function definitions.  The definition does "lock in" that it'll be undefined behaviour to pass arguments at any point, but the diagnostic guarantees of a prototype are not present

Comment: @M.M: OK, thanks - my bad :-S I removed the offending claim.

Answer (score 9):

- A *function declaration* is any form of line declaring a function and ending with `;`.
- A *prototype* is a function declaration where all types of the parameters are specified.

Example, prototype function declaration: `void func (void);`
Example, non-prototype function declaration: `void func ();`.

Non-prototype function declarations is an obsolescent feature (6.11.6) that may get removed from the C language. Therefore you should always use prototype format and never anything else.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identiﬁers)

> 2. ...(A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the 
>      types of its parameters.)

That is a prototype provides the information about the types of the function parameters.

Consider for example

```
void f();
```

and

```
void f( void );
```

The first declaration is not a prototype because there is nothing known about the function parameters.

The second declaration is a prototype because it provides a type list of the function parameters (it is a special kind of the type list speciﬁes that the function has no parameters).